# Does proguard have issues when using casted method reference?

Tags: java, proguard

Having an interface

```
public interface Extractor<T> {
    // another method
    void fake();

    String extract(T document);
}
```

and another interface implementing via `default` the method `fake`,

```
public interface SimpleExtractor<T> extends Extractor<T> {
    default void fake() {}
}
```

and a class accepting an `Extractor` as a constructor param

```
public class ExtractorUser<T> {
    public ExtractorUser(Extractor<T> extractor) {
    //...
    }
}
```

A `NoClassDefFoundError` occurs when this code is reached:

```
//...
new ExtractorUser<>((SimpleExtractor<T>)this::extractValues);
//...
```

`extractValues` being a method that matches the functional interface defined as `SimpleExtractor<T>`.

Has proguard some issues solving this kind of construct?

Comment: Apparently yes.